# GoogleAPI Marker not allowing on Ocean or See

Tags: ios, google-maps, marker, surface, gmsmapview

I want to put a marker on a GMSMapView. But i don´t want that the marker will be displayed on ocean or see, only earth. I searched but i don´t find an attribute or method to detect if the surface on GMSMapView is see, ocean or earth. If there is propositions? I worked under XCode, and language Objective-C.

Comment: Seems there's nothing that distinguishes land from "sea". Here's a suggestion [**example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506483/how-to-find-the-ocean-using-google-maps-api) of what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this to be global or is there a specific location you need?

You can use Google Maps Elevation layer to get if this location is above or below sea-level.

But some places have land that is below sea-level, so this solution would not always work.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro